# Updating Eclipse JFace Treeviewer when model changes?

Tags: eclipse, jface, rcp, treeviewer

I am developing a RCP application with a `TreeViewer`. While there are good number of articles to explain how to add editing support to the Viewer (and how changes in view are updated in the model), I don't find much for updating the Treeview when the underlaying model  changes. my question in short:

TreeView ----> Model updation ------ there are lots of examples

Model    ----> Treeview updation ----- this is my question

Edit:
This is what I tried  and it works. comments please

```
viewer.getTree().addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        if(e.keyCode==SWT.F3){
            System.out.println("F3 pressed... new element will be added");
            TreeParent root = (TreeParent) viewer.getInput();
            TreeParent activityRoot = (TreeParent) root.getChildren()[0];
            activityRoot.addChild(new TreeObject("NEW_ACTIVITY"));
            //viewer.update(root, null);
            viewer.refresh();
        }

    }

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data model is provided by your `content provider`, `TreeViewer` does not provide any means of changing this data - you must do that it your own code. When you have changed to model you can use the following methods to tell the `TreeViewer` about the change:

If you have just changed what needs to be shown for a single item in the tree use

```java
TreeViewer.update(object, null);
```

to get that item in the tree updated. There is also an array version of this to update multiple objects.

If you have added or removed objects in the tree use

```java
TreeViewer.refresh();
```

to rebuild the whole tree or

```java
TreeViewer.refresh(object);
```

to refresh the part of the tree start at `object`.

To tell the tree about adding and removing objects there are

```java
TreeViewer.add(parent, object);
TreeViewer.remove(object);
```

there are also array variants of these.

To help the TreeViewer find the objects call

```java
TreeViewer.setUseHashlookup(true);
```

(must be called before `TreeViewer.setInput`). Since this uses a hash table the objects should have sensible `hashCode` and `equals` methods. You can also use `TreeViewer.setComparer` to specify a different class to do the hash code and comparison.

Comment: I tried delete of Tree item using the following but its NOT working. Whats wrong with the code ?:                       if(e.keyCode==SWT.DEL){
System.out.println("DEL key pressed... element will be deleted ");
     
TreeItem item = ((Tree)e.getSource()).getSelection()[0];
viewer.remove(item.getData());
     viewer.update(viewer.getInput(),null);
viewer.refresh();
}

Comment: `viewer.remove(object)` should be enough on its own. You many need to call `TreeViewer.setUseHashlookup(true)` during creation to help the view find the objects.

Comment: The javadoc for TreeViewer.remove(Object) says **"Removes the given element from the viewer. The selection is updated if necessary.
This method should be called (by the content provider) when a single element has been removed from the model, in order to cause the viewer to accurately reflect the model. This method only affects the viewer, not the model. Note that there is another method for efficiently processing the simultaneous removal of multiple elements."** which means the model will not be updated by using this method

Comment: Yes I said use it to tell the TreeViewer about adding and removing objects. It is entirely down to you to update the model data as the TreeViewer does not know how your content provider is generating the model.

Comment: @Greg: What's unclear in this answer are the two phrases: "If you have added or removed objects in the tree" and "To tell the tree about adding and removing objects". It's not clear where the difference lies. If I have `Parent and `Child1`,`2` and `3`, and then `Child2` is removed from the model: I call `viewer.remove(Child2)` to update the tree. The description seems to say that I can call `viewer.refresh(Parent)` for the exact same effect, as the `refresh` will notice the changes in the model and remove the tree node for `Child2`. But practice shows this isn't the case. Can you clarify?

Comment: @M_M Please ask a new question with details of your issue

Comment: I have done so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329694/why-does-calling-treeviewer-refresh-not-call-the-contentproviders-getchildren)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments in this thread,one of the eclipse corner articles on using `TreeViewer` and few experimenting I had created a working model.

Here are the steps:

Create a listener interface like the following

```
public interface TreeModelListener extends EventListener {
    public void onDelete(TreeObject obj);
}
```

Let the tree Content provider to add listeners to each tree model item and implement this interface like below

```
public class TreeContentProvider implements  IStructuredContentProvider,ITreeContentProvider,TreeModelListener {

TreeViewer tv;
public TreeContentProvider(TreeViewer tv){
    this.tv=tv;
}

int cnt=0;
public void inputChanged(Viewer v, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
    cnt ++;
    System.out.println("inputChanged() called "+oldInput+" new: "+newInput);
    if(newInput!=null){

        ((TreeParent)newInput).setListener(this);
        TreeObject []items = ((TreeParent)newInput).getChildren(); 
        for(TreeObject obj : items){
            if(obj instanceof TreeParent){
                ((TreeParent) obj).setListener(this);
            }
        }

    }
}

....

@Override
public void onDelete(TreeObject obj) {
    System.out.println("Delete of "+obj+" handled by content handler ");
    TreeParent parent = obj.getParent();
    if(parent.getChildren().length<=1){
        return;
    }
    parent.removeChild(obj);
    this.tv.refresh();
}
```

}

Add a method to the `TreeModel` class as below . And obviously `TreeParent` class should have an `ArrayList` of listeners that is being used in #1 above

```
public void fireChildDelete(final TreeObject obj){

    if(this.listener!=null){
        new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("New thread spawned with ID "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
                listener.onDelete(obj);
            }

        }.run();
    }
}
```

Finally add `KeyListener` to the `TreeViewer` Object to handle Delete key as below:

```
tv.getTree().addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            if(e.keyCode==SWT.F3){
                System.out.println("F3 pressed... new element will be added");
                TreeParent root = (TreeParent) tv.getInput();
                TreeParent activityRoot = (TreeParent) root.getChildren()[0];
                activityRoot.addChild(new TreeObject("NEW_ACTIVITY"));
                //viewer.update(root, null);
                tv.refresh();
            }

            if(e.keyCode==SWT.DEL){


                System.out.println("DEL key pressed... element will be deleted "+((Tree)e.getSource()).getSelection().length);

                if(((Tree)e.getSource()).getSelection().length>0){
                    final IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) tv
                              .getSelection();
                    System.out.println("DEL#2 key pressed... element will be deleted "+selection.getFirstElement().getClass());

                    TreeParent parent =  ((TreeObject)selection.getFirstElement()).getParent();
                    parent.fireChildDelete((TreeObject) selection.getFirstElement());
                    //tv.remove(selection.getFirstElement());
                    //viewer.update(viewer.getInput(),null);
                    //tv.refresh();
                }
            }


        }

    });
```